# Show posts with ajax - Use of undefined constant postObj - assumed 'postObj'

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a homepage where there is a menu with some categories and below there are the latest posts:

```
<ul class="Categories__Menu"> 
    @foreach($categories->take(6) as $category)
        <li class="ative">
            <a href="" name="category" id="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</a>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>

<div class="row" id="posts">
 @foreach($posts as $post)
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4">
    <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{$post->image}}" alt="Card image cap">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{$post->name}}</h5>
        <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <a href="{{route('posts.show', ['id' => $post->id, 'slug' => $post->slug])}}" class="btn btn-primary text-white">More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

I want that when each category is clicked to show only the posts of that category in the homepage, but in the same homepage, not in a specific category page.

So I have this Ajax:

```
$(function() {
    $("a[name='category']").on('click', function(){
        var category_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ route('category.posts',null) }}/' + category_id,
            type: 'GET',
            success:function(result){

                $('#posts').empty();
                $.each(result,function(index, postObj){
                    $('#posts').append("<p>"+postObj.name+"</p>");
                });
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error.status)
            }
        });

    });
});
```

And its working fine, but instead of show just this:

```
                $('#posts').append("<p>"+postObj.name+"</p>");
```

I want to show the posts with the real html above like:

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{$post->image}}" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{$post->name}}</h5>
            <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <a href="{{route('posts.show', ['id' => $post->id, 'slug' => $post->slug])}}" class="btn btn-primary text-white">More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So Im using like this in ajax:

```
$("a[name='category']").on('click', function(){

                var category_id = $(this).attr("id");
                alert(category_id);

                $.ajax({

                    url: '{{ route('category.posts',null) }}/' + category_id,
                    type: 'GET',
                    success:function(result){

                        $('#posts').empty();
                        $.each(result,function(index, postObj){
                            //$('#posts').append("<p>"+postObj.name+"</p>");
                            $('#posts').append("<div class=\"col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4\">\n" +
    "                        <div class=\"card box-shaddow\">\n" +
    "                            <img class=\"card-img-top\" src=\"{{postObj.image}}\" alt=\"Card image cap\">\n" +
    "                                <h5 class=\"card-title h6 font-weight-bold text-heading-blue\">{{postObj.name}}</h5>\n" +
    "                            <div class=\"card-footer d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center\">\n" +
    "\n" +
    "                                <a href=\"{{route('posts.show', ['id' => postObj.id, 'slug' => postObj.slug])}}\" class=\"btn btn-primary text-white\">More</a>\n" +
    "                            </div>\n" +
    "                        </div>\n" +
    "                    </div>");
                        });
                        console.log(result);
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        console.log(error.status)
                    }
                });

            });
```

But it appears an error:

```
Use of undefined constant postObj - assumed 'postObj'
```

Do you know why?

PostController:

```
public function WhereHasCategory(Request $request)
    {
        $posts = Post::whereHas('categories', function ($categories) use (&$request) {
            $categories->where('id',$request->id);
        })->get();

        return response()->json($posts);
    }
```

Route to the ajax part:

```
Route::get('posts/where/category/{id}','\PostController@WhereHasCategory')->name('category.posts');
```

Method to return the homepage view:

```
public function index(){
        return view('home')
            ->with('categories', Category::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get())
            ->with('posts', Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(8)->get());
    }
```

Comment: Can you add sample format of result in your question which you are getting from ajax call

Comment: For example acessing "http://proj.test/posts/where/category/1" I get: [
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Title post",
"description": "description",
"image": "uploads/posts/test.png",
"status": "E",
"slug": "post-title",
}
]

Comment: where is "title" key in your sample data (postObj.title)

Comment: It should be name, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you refer to variable in Blade template with **$postObj**, not **postObj**. I can see you use it without **$**, like **postObj.image** in your  tag.

Comment: Thanks, but now it appears "Use of undefined constant image - assumed 'image'", using {{$postObj.image}}.

Comment: Well, you should use PHP syntax $postObj->image, not javascript syntax.

Comment: I tested like that but it appears "Undefined variable: postObj ".

Comment: Do you pass that correctly to your blade template? I can't tell, you haven't posted that part of your code.

Comment: I update the question with that code, do you know where is the issue?

Comment: You posted controller that returns some JSON from your application. The problem is with the code that renders the view that starts with "$("a[name='category']").on('click', function(){". Post that part.

Comment: I upate the quesiton with the method that returns the homepage with the posts and categories.

Comment: You don't pass postObj variable to the view, just posts and categories.

Comment: So, here " $.each(result,function(index, postObj){" should be "                        $.each(result,function(index, {{$posts}}){"? But the ajax makes another request to get only the posts with the selected category.

Comment: At first only appear the latest 8 posts. But then with the ajax request it should get the posts of the selected category, clear the posts and show instead the  posts of the selected category.